# continuous functions, product topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have to prove the following statement:

$(X,\mathcal{T}_X), (Y,\mathcal{T}_Y), (Z,\mathcal{T}_Z)$ topological spaces.

$h=(f,g):Z\rightarrow X\times Y, h(z)=(f(z),g(z))$ is continuous if and only if $f:Z\rightarrow X$ and $g:Z\rightarrow Y$ are continuous.

I started with the definition of continuous functions, but it didn't help me to prove the statement. Can somebody help me? thank you!

Comment: You have two things to prove, the "if" and the "only if". Which part have you done, and which part are you stuck on?

Comment: actually, both..

Comment: Do you know that the projection functions $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$ are continuous?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\pi_X: X \times Y \rightarrow X$ be the left projection (mapping $(x,y)$ to $x$, and $\pi_Y: X \times Y \rightarrow Y$ be the right projection, mapping $(x,y)$ to $y$. Both are continuous on $X \times Y$ by the definition of the product topology.

$\pi_X \circ h = f$ and $\pi_Y \circ h = g$ proves one implication.

If $U \times V$ is basic open in $X \times Y$, then $h^{-1}[U \times V] = f^{-1}[U] \cap g^{-1}[V]$, which will show the other implication, as continuity need only be checked on base elements.

Comment: Thank you! For clarification: the implication (the first in your answer) uses the fact that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous, right?

Comment: @JBIBB It does, yes.

Comment: The second implication I find difficult to understand.. why is this enough to proof the backward implication? I understand it is enough to check continuity only on base elements, but why are the base elements continuous?

Comment: @JBIBB You need to show the inverse image of $h$ of a basic open set is open, assuming $f$ and $g$ are continuous. And the expression is clearly open in that case.

Comment: Ooh, I get it, thanks!

Comment: @JBIBB Do check the claimed identities, of course.