# Clarification of Proof about Continuous functions and Product Topology

Tags: general-topology

So, I am trying to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585422/continuous-functions-product-topology) problem, and I need some hint on how to prove  $h^{-1}[U\times V] = f^{-1}(U) \cap g^{-1} (V)$ as shown in the first solution. I know I have to show mutual inclusion, but how can I further decompose $h^{-1}[U\times V]$? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean to say that $(f(x),g(x)) \in U \times V$?

Comment: Write the definitions of both sets and compare.

Comment: Ah, yes! I think I got this. It's a very obvious question but I just stucked here. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it. Let $x \in h^{-1}(U\times V)$, then $h(x) = (f(x), g(x))\in U
\times V$. Then we have $f(x)\in U$, $g(x)\in V$. Then, $x\in f^{-1}(U)$, and $x\in f^{-1}(V)$ and the rest should be obvious.

Thank you guys!